# How does Ruby Time#dst?

Tags: ruby, time, standard-library

Perhaps a daft question that demonstrates my lack of understanding of daylight saving fundamentals, but as per the title, how does `Time.dst?` know whether the time object is indeed true or false?

Presumably this must be discernible by the combination of the Date and the Timezone, but then that doesn't make sense as lower latitudes in timezones don't use daylight savings? Therefore surely it must  need location to discern #dst? ?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with time zones and daylight savings time, Ruby, like just about everything else, is [calling](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/time.c#L873) the [`localtime_r` C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/localtime.html). This puts the time in a C structure called [`tm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html) which includes a field called `isdst`.  Ruby is reading that flag.

`localtime_r` calculates `isdst` first by getting your time zone from the global `tzname` variable. `tzname` is determined by calling [`tzset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tzset.html). How `tzset` does its job is system dependent. It can come from the TZ environment variable, reading a file, or querying an OS service.

For example.

```
# Time zone from the system.
$ ruby -e 'puts Time.now.zone; puts Time.now.dst?'
PDT
true

# Time zone from the TZ environment variable.
$ TZ='Australia/Brisbane' ruby -e 'puts Time.now.zone; puts Time.now.dst?'
AEST
false
```

Once it has the time zone, `localtime_r` can convert from [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) to the desired time zone (using the rules which applied on that date) using the ["tz database"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) aka "tzdata" aka "zoneinfo" aka "the Olson database" after its creator Arthur David Olson. Previously a private effort, this is now maintained by [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). It is a set of files installed on your system, or shipped with Ruby, which contains [Far More Than Everything You Ever Want To Know About Time Zones and Daylight Savings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Example_zone_and_rule_lines).

The tz database [treats daylight savings (and other weird things like War and Peace time) as just another time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Daylight_saving_time_.28DST.29_rules). Time zone records are kept going all the way back as far as we've had time zones. Before we had time zones [solar noon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noon#Solar_noon) for that location is used. Because of these historical complications and shifting time zones, the tz database prefers to [work with cities (such as "America/New York")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and determine the time zone for you.

The [time zone data files](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) contain extensive commentary and background, if you're interested in the history of calendaring they're a fascinating read.

Comment: Hmm, good work @Schwern, great thorough answer. Looking up the Olson database as we speak whilst rubbing my thighs in glee at this new font of time knowledge courtesy of you and your answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby 2.2.0 [`Time.dst?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-dst-3F) refers to the [`time_isdst(...)` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/time.c#L4258-L4266) in `time.c`:

```c
// ...
return tobj->vtm.isdst ? Qtrue : Qfalse
```

Which seems correspond to the [UNIX `struct tm tm_isdt` member](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/time.h.html), after plenty of mangling:

```c
int    tm_isdst daylight savings flag
```

Search for `tm_isdst` and `isdst` in [`time.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/time.c) to read about how it is computed.